# How to track a service whose response is keep changing after a minute in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am working with angular js (1.x).

I need to display some data which is coming from backend. For that I am calling a service.

Problem is that the response keep changing periodically. But still I didnt use setTimeInterval as this may overload backend due to continuously sending request from UI. So I let user to manually refresh the page to update the data.

Is there any way in which I can auto-update the data without having to use setTimeInterval?

Comment: use websockets.

Comment: You could also have a look at something like Firebase or RethinkDB

Answer (score 0):

**What is a websocket?**

WebSockets is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

**AngularJs + Websockets**

You can use ng-websocket for angularjs

https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket

or

[AngularJS WebSocket Service Example](http://clintberry.com/2013/angular-js-websocket-service/)

Comment: so we have to put the service inside websocket.on() method so that it will automatically keep calling the service in the background?

Comment: It itself acts a service. Please go through the docs completely. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm